# finding MGU for symmetrical expression

Tags: artificial-intelligence, unification

given this pair of expressions, is it possible to find a MGU for it?

1. f(x,y)
2. f(y,x)

I wanted to say that it is possible, when x/y, but I wasn't sure if that's legal.
what do you guys say?

thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "x/y"? why is x = y not the mgu?

Comment: that's what i meant but I was wondered if that's a legal solution, since in the given examples there are 2 inputs which may be different, and in the MGU both of the inputs are identical.
perhaps i'm missing something about this subject..

Comment: why are they different?

Comment: by the way, is this prolog notation or logical notation? i.e., are x and y variables or constants?

Comment: logical notation - they are variables
when looking on the logical expression f(x,y), aren't we suppose to assume that x and y are different?

Comment: this is perhaps the most common error students make in logical programming: assuming that two different variables must be different. They are not. x=y is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these terms can be easily unified, producing the assertion x=y as a side effect.

Comment: I think that "side effect" is a misleading term to people who would benefit from the answer. I would prefer "result" or "unifier".